# MYSQL 5.7.17 FULL TEXT SEARCH

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search

Table structure after Alter table

```
CREATE TABLE `WINNER` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DELETED` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `NO_OF_AWARDS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PHONE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `country_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `orgId_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_kkk28h9hpbjqvfis7hr4njm1t` (`PHONE`),
  KEY `FK8nj02saxptd0qs5mh7ix6q82a` (`country_ID`),
  KEY `FKlosg52h1cxfljriqt9vhf1b5o` (`orgId_ID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `PAGINATION_SEARCH` (`FIRST_NAME`,`LAST_NAME`,`PHONE`,`EMAIL`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8nj02saxptd0qs5mh7ix6q82a` FOREIGN KEY (`country_ID`) REFERENCES `COUNTRY` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKlosg52h1cxfljriqt9vhf1b5o` FOREIGN KEY (`orgId_ID`) REFERENCES `ORGANISATION` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE `WINNER`
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `PAGINATION_SEARCH` (`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `PHONE`, `EMAIL`);
```

The following search throws syntax error.

```
 select * from `WINNER` WHERE MATHCH(`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `PHONE`, `EMAIL`)
     AGAINST ('aa' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AGAINST ('aa' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

There is spelling mistake in below query for MATCH

```
select * from `WINNER` WHERE MATCH(`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `PHONE`, `EMAIL`)
     AGAINST ('aa' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a typo in word match, the correct query is this:

```
 select * from `WINNER` WHERE MATCH(`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `PHONE`, `EMAIL`)
 AGAINST ('aa' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```